# given array keys only return keys from form

Tags: php, arrays

I just wrote an array keys to only return the exact keys that exists in the form $_POST

```
function array_key_exists_exact($strkeys, $search) 
{
    $keys = split('\|',$strkeys);
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
      if(array_key_exists($key,$search))
      {
          $newkeys[$key]=$key;
          unset($newkeys[$key]);
      }
      else
      {     
      }
    }
    return $newkeys;
}
```

however it is returning all the keys, what am i doing wrong.

eg:

```
$str="email|phone|address|school|country";
array_key_exists_exact($str, $_POST)
```

should only return whats contained in the form based on the $str.

so if my form has:

```
<form>
<input type=text name=email>
<input type=text name=phone>
<input type=text name=address>
</form>
```

out put should be:

```
array("email", "phone", "address")
```

right now it outputs this: `array("email", "phone", "address", "school", "country").`

and yes, i must pass `$str="email|phone|address|school|country";`

Comment: I'm surprised this outputs anything at all, given that you're unsetting the entry in `$newkeys` right after you create them.

Comment: it actually outputs:) i thought i should unset it when i find a key. thanks

Comment: What is the point of doing `$newkeys[$key]` and then immediately unsetting it again? Might as well just eliminate the entire foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `array_intersect`?

```
$possible = array('email', 'phone', ...);
$existing = array_intersect($possible, array_keys($_POST));
var_dump($existing);
```

Comment: so i output $possible, then i output $array_keys($_POST) and its like this array([0]=>email,[1]=>phone) does intersect uses the key or the value?

Comment: `array_intersect` uses the values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your function, **split()** is deprecated for a start so I thought I'd write a new one, here it is:

```
$str="email|phone|phone|school|country";


$_POST['email'] = 'test2';
$_POST['school'] = 'test1'; 


function return_array_keys($strkeys,$search) {
    $strings = explode('|',$strkeys);
    foreach($strings as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists(trim($key),$search)) {
            $newkeys[$key] = $search[$key]; 
        }else {
            continue;   
        }
    }
    return $newkeys;
}

$test = return_array_keys($str, $_POST);

var_dump($test);
```